# toggleClass doesn't work with display:block

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have 4 divs which have style="display: none" property and when I try to change the property to display: block through toggleClass it doesn't works.
JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#add_client").click(function () {
        $("#inputs").toggleClass("shown");
    });

    $("#show_clients").click(function () {
        $("#show_information").toggleClass("shown");
    });

    $("#show_free_rooms").click(function () {
        $("#show-free-rooms").toggleClass("shown");
    });

    $("#search-by").click(function () {
        $("#find_room_by_name").toggleClass("shown");
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
.shown{
    display: block;
}
```

Can anyone explain me what is wrong with my code?

Comment: Specificity https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity don't use an inline style....

Comment: "*change the property through toggleClass*" - toggleClass changes the `class`, not the `style` property.

Comment: The fix is to default-hide them in the css, in the basic format, this would be to remove your `style=` in the HTML then add `div { display:hidden }` - obviously this would affect all divs, so you might want to give the toggle-able elements an specific class and apply to that.

Comment: If you really want to do it this way, you can add `!important` to the CSS. Then it will override the inline style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with your sample is that the display declaration in CSS is not overwriting the attribute set via inline style, because the latest has higher priority. You can define the `display: none` state in CSS too, with a similar level of specificity.

See below a running sample, notice I deliberately made the second item fail by declaring the attribute style in the HTML property as you did initially, so the difference with the rest of the elements can be noticed:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#add_client").click(function () {
    $("#inputs").toggleClass("shown");
  });

  $("#show_clients").click(function () {
    $("#show_information").toggleClass("shown");
  });

  $("#show_free_rooms").click(function () {
    $("#show-free-rooms").toggleClass("shown");
  });

  $("#search-by").click(function () {
    $("#find_room_by_name").toggleClass("shown");
  });
});
```

```css
.myitems div {
  display: none;
}

.myitems div.shown {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="add_client">add client</button> |
<button id="show_clients">show client (not working)</button> |
<button id="show_free_rooms">show_free_rooms</button> |
<button id="search-by">search-by</button>

<div class="myitems">
<div id="inputs">
  inputs div content
</div>

<div id="show_information" style="display: none">
  show_information div content (not working)
</div>

<div id="show-free-rooms">
  show-free-rooms div content
</div>

<div id="find_room_by_name">
  find_room_by_name div content
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Inline styles added to an element (e.g., style="font-weight: bold;") always overwrite any normal styles in author stylesheets, and therefore, can be thought of as having the [highest specificity.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#inline_styles)

A possible solution to your problem would be to remove the inline style, and instead a class, say `hidden` to those elements. And in your stylesheet,

```css
.hidden {
    display: none;
}

.shown{
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Always?  No.  https://jsfiddle.net/rvq1329k/